# Converting Input into a $String Problems

Tags: php

I am using a php form where the user enters a file name into an input box and then the form SHOULD use the $path, $name, and $ending together to make a correct path to open the file and make a chance from ]no[ to ]yes[.

But I do not have the format correct because it isn't working. It does work if I enter everything into the $path, but it isn't converting the text box file name correctly.

Any help is greatly Appreciated!

```
############### Code Below ###################
<?php

echo "<table border = 0><tr><td align=left valign=center>";


echo "Please paste the file name below:</br>";
echo "<form method='POST' action='3.php'>";
echo "<input type = 'text' name='$name'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>";
echo "</form>";
$path="/home/users/web/b1262/moo.mybidszcom/sandbox/";
$ending='.dat';
$file = ("$path$name$ending");
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

$fh = fopen($file, "w");
$file_contents = str_replace(']no[',']yes[',$file_contents);
fwrite($fh, $file_contents);
fclose($fh);

echo "</td><td></td></tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: You need to read up on a) some basic debugging techniques, and b) and more importantly, [path traversal attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$_POST['theValue']` isset, if not, show the form, otherwise execute the code.

```
if(!isset($_POST['theValue'])){
    echo <<< EOF
    <table border = 0>
        <tr>
            <td align=left valign=center>
                Please paste the file name below:</br>
                <form method='POST' action='3.php'>
                <input type ='text' name='theValue'/>
                <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
EOF;
}else{
    $name = $_POST['theValue'];
    $path="/home/users/web/b1262/moo.mybidszcom/sandbox/";
    $ending='.dat';
    $file = "{$path}{$name}{$ending}";
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $file_contents = str_replace(']no[',']yes[',$file_contents);
    file_put_contents($file, $file_contents);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should fix like that

```
############### Code Below ###################
<?php

echo "<table border = 0><tr><td align=left valign=center>";


echo "Please paste the file name below:</br>";
echo "<form method='POST' action='3.php'>";
echo "<input type = 'text' name='name'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>";
echo "</form>";
$path="/home/users/web/b1262/moo.mybidszcom/sandbox/";
$ending='.dat';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$file = ("$path$name$ending");
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

$fh = fopen($file, "w");
$file_contents = str_replace(']no[',']yes[',$file_contents);
fwrite($fh, $file_contents);
fclose($fh);

echo "</td><td></td></tr></table>";
?>
```

And your file name must be 3.php

Your code didn't work because when you send post to server. Your input value will be stored as $_POST['your_input_name']. $_POST is your form's method, it mabe $_GET if you change your form's method to GET